# Date of question displays wrongly

Tags: bug, user-interface, tooltips, dates

It displays as "yesterday" but today is February 20 and question's date is February 18.

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

The moment I'm writing this answer the UTC time is 06:49, Feb 20.

In the following GIF file, there are two questions are listed.

The first question posted on `2019-02-18 06:54:12` UTC time. It is showing as posted on yesterday, if the question/answer posted time is crossed the current UTC time (06:49), it will display as 2 days ago as mentioned in the second question. The second question's posted time is on `2019-02-18 05:38:15` UTC time.

Since both questions are posted with in 1 hour time range, but based on the current UTC time the calculations are done. So it is not a bug and it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

So the question you are mentioned on `2019-02-18 10:27:48`, if you are verifying it after 10:28 UTC, it will displayed as posted 2 days ago.

> [image: GIF]

Comment: I understood the logic, but it's weird to synonimize  "day ago" and "24 hours ago" because day starts at midnight